# Finding Expected Stock Price in Scenario Analysis

Tags: probability

I have four events each with different probabilities. P(e1)= 0.15, P(e2)= 0.24, p(e3)= 0.2, p(e4)= 0.15. e1= low sales momentum, e2= low economic growth, e3= short turnaround period, e4= reduced industry competition.

Under each individual event I have a different stock price. Price(e1)= Price(e2)=Price(e3)=24 , Price (e4)=30.

i want to calculate the expected stock price, if all four events occur simultaneously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the information given I don't think there's a determined price if all four events occur simultaneously.

Consider the example of two simultaneous coin tosses. If only the first coin is heads, then the price is \$1. If only the second coin is heads, then the price is \$2. So what's the price if both coins are heads simultaneously? We don't generally know. We would need to determine a value or function to use.

Comment: could i use a weighted average? I only really need an approximation.
so e.g. (0.15/(0.15+0.24+0.2+0.15) *24 +... + (0.15/ (0.15+0.24+0.2+015)*30?

Comment: If you only need an approximation, then just a regular average might be enough. But it's probably ok to weight by probability too. Just be aware that the weighted average will skew towards the more probable prices. Ultimately we would want to flesh out the model to determine the most appropriate weighting or approach.